# Cannot import name util

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use SQLAlchemy. However I am unable to import it into my python script.

I've activated the python console and inputed "import sqlalchemy" and it throws me and error as shown below.

```
>>>import sqlalchemy
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py2.7.egg/sqlalchemy/schema.py", line 31, in <module>
from sqlalchemy import exc, util, dialects
ImportError: cannot import name util
```

I would appreciate it if anyone who has overcame this problem shares it with me. Thanks

Comment: is there more stacktrace information available?

Answer (score 2):

My answer is mostly unrelated to the original question and circumstances, but this thread appears as the first question when searching for the error-message and it was a pita to fix this, so I might as well add my case with Pyramid and SQLAlchemy:

In conjunction with Pyramid, I had the same error ("ImportError: cannot import name util"). After hours of trial and error the only reason turned out that in production.ini I had set:

```
[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 80
```

I was also using Apache2 on port 80, seemed odd that this should be the same. After changing the port to e.g. 6543, the error disappeared and the WSGI server worked. None of the apache2-settings (WSGIPythonHome,WSGIPythonPath) where necessary.

Apparently unrelated and I don't know why the port-conflict caused this error, but it might help someone else with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

util is under sqlalchemy.orm
so `from sqlalchemy.orm import util` should work

Comment: You are right, there is a module `sqlalchemy.orm.util`. But `SA` also has a package `sqlalchemy.util` (which BTW is used by the former). In fact, the code posted is from `SA` itself...

Comment: yes, the code `from sqlalchemy import exc, util, dialects` can run on my machine.. so it is weird, maybe it is caused by a different problem..