# ImportError in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, apache, sqlalchemy

I am trying to install [vatic](http://web.mit.edu/vondrick/vatic/). I kept on getting server errors and so I decided to have a look at the log and I found this. From what I understand, I need to change the "import util" statement as apparently there are [two versions of util](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641777/cannot-import-name-util) and I need to specify the correct one. Here comes the silly part of the question. Where do I get this .py files. I am posting the log but I went into the bdist.linux-x86_64 folder within the vatic directory but it was empty. I am not sure where to get this file.

```
    [:error]  mod_wsgi (pid=32753): Target WSGI script '/home/<user>/work/vatic/server.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
    [:error]  mod_wsgi (pid=32753): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/<user>/work/vatic/server.py'.
    [:error]  Traceback (most recent call last):
    [:error]  File "/home/<user>/work/vatic/server.py", line 5, in <module>
    [:error]     from turkic.server import handler, application
    [:error]  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/turkic-0.2.5-py2.7.egg/turkic/server.py", line 15, in <module>
    [:error]     from turkic.database import session
    [:error]  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/turkic-0.2.5-py2.7.egg/turkic/database.py", line 12, in <module>
    [:error]     from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    [:error]  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    [:error]  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/sql/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    [:error]  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/sql/expression.py", line 31, in <module>
    [:error]  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/sql/functions.py", line 11, in <module>
    [:error]  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py", line 17, in <module>
    [:error]  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/processors.py", line 19, in <module>
    [:error]     ImportError: cannot import name util
```

Answer (score 0):

> if you use turkic 0.2.5 , downgrade to 0.2.4
>
> ## on my enviroment , It works
>
> $ sudo -H pip list | grep turkic turkic (0.2.5)
>
> $ sudo pip uninstall turkic $ sudo pip install turkic==0.2.4
>
> ---

Comment: turkic doesn't work for me at all on the command line after installing it with pip.  I think this was a step backwards for my system.